# No sonar-runner option in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm looking to install sonarQube on our jenkins server.

The documentation i can find tells me to configure sonar-runner in

```
Jenkins --> manage Jenkins -->  Configure system
```

however there is no 'sonar runner' option there.
There is a 'sonar' option where i configured my sonar server, and the sonar plugin is installed and up to date.

How do i get the sonar-runner configuration to show up?

(We want the standalone sonar job not the maven on as this is a project without maven.)

Comment: Which version of the SonarQube Jenkins plugin do you have?

Comment: 2.1 --> 
Sonar Plugin
Quickly benefit from Sonar, an open-source dashboard based on many analysis tools like Checkstyle, PMD and Cobertura.
2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. So, if I understand well:

1. Going into Manage Jenkins' -> 'Manage Plugin' -> tab 'Installed' in the Plugin manager, you can see 'Jenkins Sonar plugin' in the installed plugins.
   --> Beware that there is a SonarGraph plugin that is not the proper one. Please verify you have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNZLG.jpg
2. You say you can install the sonar server part in Jenkins. I understand you refer to this doc http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin#ConfiguringSonarQubeJenkinsPlugin-AddingSonarQubeServer, and more specifically section 'Adding SonarQube Server' point 2 and 3.
   --> Can you confirm that you have this 'Sonar' part under you Jenkins configuration ?
3. If yes to previous 1 & 2, you should also have the SonarQube Runner part available in Jenkins, as in the previous doc and the post on my blog. 
   --> Can you confirm this is the part that is lacking ?
4. Can you try this: 
   Jenkins -> New Job -> Select 'Build a free-style software project', enter a job Name -> click Ok.
   Section Build -> 'Add build Step': can you see the 'Invoke standalone Sonar analysis' menu : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TmFr.jpg ?
5. You have SonarQube runner installed and correctly configured: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runnerhttp://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner

Do not hesitate to ask for further precision.

Comment: i can confirm that step 3 is the one that is missing.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somehow related to step 5 though. i understood from the instalation guides that installing sonar runner is something you need when you run a standalone sonar job from console, installing it on jenkins is never mentioned, and doing things like changing the PATH var on my jenkins master (who doesnt build, the slaves do) seems weird.

Comment: You should have SonarQube runner installed (point 5). This post is an example of installing/updating SonarQube runner with Jenkins http://qualilogy.com/en/upgrade-sonarqube-runner-jenkins/. Just try and look if it works. There may be other solution without sonar runner, like Maven, but I am not a mavenist.

Comment: I expect this to be the solution, albeit a bit weird (having to install stuff on my jenkins master). At this time i have a working version with ant, wich seems to work just as well so i wont test this anymore, but will accept this as the (likely) answer

Answer (score 29):

In newer versions of Jenkins (like 2.2), the sonarqube runner configuration is under

> Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration

Thats the solution :)

Comment: Thanks. i found it there. But I still don't see option to Invoke standalone Sonar analysis from build job or post build job

Answer (score 0):

I can see both `Sonar` (just above *E-mail Notification* section) and `Sonar Runner` in `Jenkins > Configure System` section.

[image]

I have Jenkins 1.547 and Sonar Plugin 2.1 installed. However, please note that, as per [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341) link, Jenkins 1.491+ and Sonar plugin 2.1 will suffice.

Comment: This is what is see in the explanations found online, but that "Sonar runner" part is just not there

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: jenkins version: 1.576

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue.
Solution is that you need to run sonar-runner outside jenkins once and then restart jenkins.

To run sonar-runner outside jenkins. Download sonar-runner as mentioned in the steps @
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing

Create a **sonar-project.properties** file at the root of you code base. below link describes the content of the file. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner

Run sonar-runner.bat from the codebase.

Once the sonar analysis is done, Start Jenkins Jenkins will now show the sonar-runner option in configure page.