# SONAR RUNNER option not showing in Jenkins Build section

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

- I am using SonarQube 4.4.1 && SonarRunner 2.4
- First I was started SonarQube server[ localhost:9000] .Then i was started Jenkins sever[localhost:8080/jenkins ].
- Third step i installed sonarqube in jenkins plugin page.
- Then i stoped andstarted the sonar and jenkins server.
- Next i am going to configure sonar and sonar runner in jenkins configuration path.
- Then i add new Item in Jenkins Home page lable.
  *Next i am going to build section and click the " invoke standalone sonar runner "..
- not showing the sonar-runner lable.

Comment: what do you mean with "in Jenkins configuration path"? Have you followed this guide step-by-step? http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand precisely what is the problem, but it might be related to this [No sonar-runner option in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726296/no-sonar-runner-option-in-jenkins/25792861#25792861).

In that case, just run once the Sonar-runner(.bat) outside of Jenkins.

Hope it helps,
Regards