# SonarQube Integration with Jenkins and Jira

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jira, sonar-runner

I am supposed to **setup SonarQube** and I have Jenkins and Jira already running in the server. I need to know whether **SonarQube has to be integrated with Jenkins alone or Jenkins and Jira both**. I did a google and searched forums and found that plugins are available for integrating with Jenkins. But could not find integrations for Sonarqube and Jira. I also have Github configured for Version control.
Has anyone integrated Jenkins,SonarQube and Jira together. Anyone has idea on these integrations

Comment: Fyi https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217471/sonarqube-connector-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no integrations between SonarQube and Jira. The Git integration to show last committer on the line and assign new issues should happen automatically - that plugin is pre-loaded in new installations.

To fire your analyses from Jenkins, use the [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins)

Comment: I searched forums but could not find answers about Jira and Sonarqube integrations.Now I can think of integrating SQ and Jenkins.

Comment: @Ann - I have installed sonar.hpi plugin then in Manage Jenkins>Configure System I could see only SonarQube Servers. What plugin is available to have sonarqube scanners option available in the URL mentioned http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

Comment: It's in there. Look for 'SonarQube Scanner'

Comment: Just checked jenkins plugin page and could not find plugin 'SonarQube Scanner'. The jenkins plugin page is https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/. I see the page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins. In order to configure SQ scanner I need to have SQ runner. This is already asked in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726296/no-sonar-runner-option-in-jenkins which I have to refer now. I will check the post.

Comment: The global SonarQube Scanner configuration section is add by the plugin you've already installed

Comment: yeah, SQ Scanner section is available in Global Tool Configuration in Jenkins.